# Flutter 2.x.x plugin flutter_secure_storage no funciona después de compilar en modo de lanzamiento

Tags: flutter, dart

Cuando compilo la app y la monto en `play console`, la descargo para el dispositivo físico dando una falla pues al identificarme como usuario, se queda congelada: no conecta con el servidor (nodejs) para realizar la consulta a MongoDB. Llevo investigando toda la semana y no doy con la solución, sé que me da un error en el plugin `flutter_secure_Storage`, y creo que por ahí debe estar el problema: cuando la corro en modo debug en visual studio, tanto en emulador android como IOS, y dispositivo físico se conecta perfectamente y realiza la consulta al la BD.
Este problema ha surgido desde que actualicé a la versión 2.x.x de Flutter, antes corría perfectamente con el archivo lanzado a la tienda. Seguí la actualización que colgó Fernando en el curso de Flutter: Tu guía completa para IOS Y Android.

Paso log de la compilación de la app en formato xxx.aab

```
 flutter build appbundle --verbose
   ............
    [   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0/
    [   +7 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at ....../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_web-2.0.0/
    [   +4 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0/
    [ +204 ms] Found plugin flutter_secure_storage at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-4.1.0/
    [  +23 ms] Found plugin path_provider at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.1/
    [   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_linux-2.0.0/
    [   +1 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_macos-2.0.0/
    [   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.0.0/
    [  +15 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at .../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/
    [   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at ./snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0/
    [   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at .../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_macos-2.0.0/
    [  +14 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_web-2.0.0/
    [   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_windows-2.0.0/
    [  +44 ms] Generating .../development/incidencias/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
    [ +130 ms] Building without sound null safety
    [        ] For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
    [  +36 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
    [   +6 ms] Using gradle from /home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/android/gradlew.
    [   +2 ms] /home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/android/gradlew mode: 33277 rwxrwxr-x.
    [  +12 ms] executing: /home/diegofdez/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
    [ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/diegofdez/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
    [        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
               OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
               OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b3-6222593, mixed mode)
    [   +2 ms] executing: [/home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/android/] ..../development/incidencias/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true
    -Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 -Ptarget=lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=true bundleRelease
    [+1586 ms] > Configure project :app
    [        ] WARNING: DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete.
    [        ] It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
    [   +1 ms] Use 'android.enableR8' in gradle.properties to switch between R8 and Proguard.
    [ +364 ms] > Task :app:cleanMergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :app:extractProguardFiles
    [        ] > Task :app:preReleaseBuild
    [        ] > Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
    [        ] > Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    [+1997 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
    [        ] [ +113 ms] executing: [/home/diegofdez/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [        ] [  +72 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [        ] [        ] 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3....
    [   +2 ms] [   +1 ms] executing: [/home/diegofdez/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git tag --points-at 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b....
    [        ] [  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
    [        ] [        ] 2.0.3
    [        ] [  +57 ms] executing: [..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [        ] [   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [        ] [        ] origin/stable
    [        ] [        ] executing: [..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [        ] [   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [        ] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    [        ] [  +61 ms] executing: [.../snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [        ] [   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [        ] [        ] stable
    [        ] [  +81 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [ +112 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] [ +120 ms] Initializing file store
    [        ] [  +43 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
    [        ] [  +11 ms] kernel_snapshot: Starting due to {}
    [        ] [  +25 ms] /home/diegofdez/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
    ...../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
    ...../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk_product/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Ddart.vm.profile=false
    -Ddart.vm.product=true --aot --tfa --packages ..../development/incidencias/.dart_tool/package_config.json --output-dill
    ..../development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52bec4ee6bb3bda43908/app.dill --depfile
    ...../development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52bec4ee6bb3bda43908/kernel_snapshot.d package:incidencias/main.dart
    [+40277 ms] [+40953 ms] kernel_snapshot: Complete
    [ +700 ms] [ +756 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
    [        ] [  +10 ms] executing: /home/diegofdez/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm-release/linux-x64/gen_snapshot --deterministic
    --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf --elf=...../development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52bec4ee6bb3b..../armeabi-v7a/app.so --strip --no-sim-use-hardfp
    --no-use-integer-division /home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52bec4....a43908/app.dill
    [   +1 ms] [        ] aot_android_asset_bundle: Starting due to {}
    [        ] [  +21 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
    [        ] [        ] executing: ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/linux-x64/gen_snapshot --deterministic
    --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf --elf=/home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed5....bb3bda43908/arm64-v8a/app.so --strip
    ..../development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52be....43908/app.dill
    [   +1 ms] [        ] android_aot_release_android-x64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
    [        ] [        ] executing: /home/diegofdez/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-x64-release/linux-x64/gen_snapshot --deterministic
    --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf --elf=/home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52...b3bda43908/x86_64/app.so --strip
    ..../development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1ed52....bda43908/app.dill
    [ +398 ms] [ +319 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more information see #56466.
    [  +96 ms] [  +80 ms] Running command: ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev
   ...../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/const_finder.dart.snapshot --kernel-file
    /home/diegofdez/development/incidencias/.dart_tool/flutter_build/9ac98e74a1....6bb3bda43908/app.dill --class-library-uri package:flutter/src/widgets/icon_data.dart --class-name
    IconData
    [+5500 ms] [+5594 ms] Running font-subset: ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/font-subset
    ..../development/incidencias/build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf
    ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/font_awesome_flutter-8.11.0/lib/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf, using codepoints 61447 61557
    [   +1 ms] [   +1 ms] Running font-subset: .../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/font-subset
    .../development/incidencias/build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/flutter_assets/packages/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
    ../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/font_awesome_flutter-8.11.0/lib/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf, using codepoints 62868 62922 61587 61530 63163 63460
    62197
    [  +98 ms] [   +1 ms] Running font-subset: ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/font-subset
    .../development/incidencias/build/app/intermediates/flutter/release/flutter_assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
    ..../snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/material_fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf, using codepoints 59495 58791 58792 58974 58796 58962 58963 59109 58915 59828
    59528 59371 58715 59834 59379 58959 59595 59644 59478 59462 58956 58972 59136 59087 58795 59757 58834 58804
    [   +1 ms] [  +85 ms] aot_android_asset_bundle: Complete
    [+31298 ms] [+31315 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm64: Complete
    [ +199 ms] [ +171 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
    [        ] [  +30 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm64: Complete
    [ +199 ms] [ +160 ms] android_aot_release_android-x64: Complete
    [ +100 ms] [ +141 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-x64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
    [  +99 ms] [  +34 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-x64: Complete
    [+1800 ms] [+1772 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm: Complete
    [        ] [  +96 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
    [  +99 ms] [  +23 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm: Complete
    [ +100 ms] [ +104 ms] _composite: Starting due to {}
    [        ] [        ] _composite: Complete
    [        ] [   +1 ms] Persisting file store
    [        ] [  +20 ms] Done persisting file store
    [        ] [  +23 ms] build succeeded.
    [        ] [  +21 ms] "flutter assemble" took 82.091ms.
    [        ] [   +7 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 0ms
    [        ] [   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
    [        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
    [        ] [        ] exiting with code 0
    [+2897 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildRelease
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:mergeReleaseShaders
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:packageReleaseAssets
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:mergeReleaseShaders
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:packageReleaseAssets
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:mergeReleaseShaders
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:packageReleaseAssets
    [ +194 ms] > Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseResValues
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseResources
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:packageReleaseResources
    [  +99 ms] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:generateReleaseResValues
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:generateReleaseResources
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:parseReleaseLocalResources
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:javaPreCompileRelease
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:processReleaseManifest
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:packageReleaseResources
    [  +97 ms] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:parseReleaseLocalResources
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:processReleaseManifest
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:javaPreCompileRelease
    [  +99 ms] > Task :shared_preferences:generateReleaseRFile
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    [  +99 ms] > Task :path_provider:generateReleaseResValues
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:generateReleaseResources
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:packageReleaseResources
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:generateReleaseRFile
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:parseReleaseLocalResources
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:processReleaseManifest
    [ +298 ms] > Task :shared_preferences:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [ +199 ms] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [   +1 ms] Note:
   **.../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-4.1.0/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage/FlutterSecureStoragePl
    ugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.**
    [   +4 ms] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [  +93 ms] > Task :path_provider:javaPreCompileRelease
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:generateReleaseRFile
    [ +999 ms] > Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
    [ +200 ms] > Task :path_provider:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:writeReleaseAarMetadata
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:writeReleaseAarMetadata
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:writeReleaseAarMetadata
    [  +96 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease
    [        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
    [        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseResources
    [ +500 ms] > Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
    [        ] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
    [  +99 ms] > Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:extractDeepLinksRelease
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:extractDeepLinksRelease
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:extractDeepLinksRelease
    [ +199 ms] > Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
    [        ] > Task :app:processReleaseManifest
    [        ] > Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
    [  +99 ms] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
    [        ] > Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
    [        ] > Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
    [  +98 ms] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
    [        ] > Task :app:processApplicationManifestReleaseForBundle
    [        ] > Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :flutter_secure_storage:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
    [  +97 ms] > Task :path_provider:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :path_provider:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
    [+1099 ms] > Task :shared_preferences:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
    [        ] > Task :shared_preferences:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
    [+2099 ms] > Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies
    [        ] > Task :app:configureReleaseDependencies
    [        ] > Task :app:parseReleaseIntegrityConfig UP-TO-DATE
    [        ] > Task :app:validateSigningRelease
    [ +799 ms] > Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
    [ +399 ms] > Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
    [        ] Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libapp.so, libflutter.so.
    [        ] > Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
    [ +699 ms] > Task :app:processReleaseResources
    [+1299 ms] > Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin
    [ +500 ms] > Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
    [        ] > Task :app:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    [ +699 ms] > Task :app:bundleReleaseResources
    [        ] > Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
    [+2001 ms] > Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
    [        ] R8: Missing class: com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication
    [        ] R8: Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue
    [        ] R8: Missing class: com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener
    [+5100 ms] > Task :app:shrinkReleaseResources
    [        ] Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 1452KB to 1437KB: Removed 1%
    [ +595 ms] > Task :app:buildReleasePreBundle
    [+6899 ms] > Task :app:packageReleaseBundle
    [+1699 ms] > Task :app:signReleaseBundle
    [        ] > Task :app:bundleRelease
    [        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    [        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    [        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    [        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 55s
    [        ] 91 actionable tasks: 82 executed, 9 up-to-date
    [ +349 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (completed in 115,8s)
    [   +8 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab (23.9MB).
    [   +6 ms] "flutter appbundle" took 116.900ms.
    [ +142 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 135ms
    [   +3 ms] Running shutdown hooks
    [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
    [        ] exiting with code 0
```

esta es la línea que me da error:

```
.../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_secure_storage-4.1.0/android/src/main/java/com/it_nomads/fluttersecurestorage/FlutterSecureStoragePl
    ugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [   +4 ms] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu aplicación funciona correctamente en DEBUG pero te presenta errores en producción el error mas común es que no desactivaste la característica de autobackup de Google Drive.

Puedes desactivar el Auto Backup de google drive siguiendo esta guía: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup

En la descripción del plugin tambien encuentras información al respecto: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge cuando se ejecuta desde un dispositivo físico, debemos dar permiso para poder hacer consultas por internet, para ello se añade la línea `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` de la carpeta `main` del directorio `android`,  justo encima de la etiqueta `<Application ...>.` introduces este código, solucionando el problema que daba en modo producción y evitando que se bloquee al realizar consulta en la red.

Antes de crea el archivo xxx.aab para subirlo a la play console, ejecuta el comando `flutter clean` dentro del proyecto.

Comment: la solución es un poco pobre, especialmente la gente que son principiante y se queda perdidos, si puede mejorar la sintaxis de su código